# Is "All the animation was done with computers" correct?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, passive-voice, plural-forms, active-vs-passive

"All the **animation** was done **with** computers."
I have two problems:
1- why does **animation** is singular? They referred to "All of them(animation)", so didn't they say **animations**.
2- it's a passive voice, so they should have used **by** not "with". Shouldn't they?
I'm so confused, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. *Animation* can be both countable and uncountable - in this case it's used as an uncountable noun to refer broadly to the entirety of work that goes into animating a movie, rather than to refer to specific *animations* (which would probably be single scenes or even single character movements).
2. The difference between using *by* and *with* in a passive voice is that *by* indicates that someone or something has done a particular thing itself (in this case, for example, if the computers were using AI or simply started and working on their own), while *with* implies a different actor (in this case presumably the actual animators) using the computers as tools with which *they*, not computers, animate the movie.

Comment: Thank you very much.